# Using Scanner.nextInt() whilst ignoring rest of line

Tags: java

I'm contemplating how to read an int using `Scanner.nextInt()`, and at the same time ignore the rest of the line or flush the input buffer to be ready for inputting the next number. *Typical usage would be to read a number where the user is likely to add units or similar after the number, and I want the scanner to be cleared out before I output a new message and ready for the next number.*

In the following code I firstly use `Scanner.nextLine()` to read rest of line, and in the second I attempted to use the `Scanner.hasNext()` to detect if anything was present. But it originally failed, so to get it to work I had to add a bug-fix related to writing the text "quit". The third read is just to finish off with a final read of an integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("1) Enter an integer (with some junk like units): ");
        int myFirstInt = scanner.nextInt();
        // Ignore rest of line
        scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("2) Enter an integer (and some junk afterwards): ");
        int mySecondInt = scanner.nextInt();

        // Clear out scanner before next read...
        String line;                    // Fix to avoid endless loop
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            line = scanner.next();
            if (line.equals("quit")) {  // Fix to avoid endless loop
                break;                  // Fix to avoid endless loop
            }                           // Fix to avoid endless loop
        }

        System.out.print("3) Enter the third integer: ");
        int myThirdInt = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("\nFirst: %d, Second: %d, Third: %d\n",
                          myFirstInt, mySecondInt, myThirdInt);
    }
}
```

A typical run with this code:

```
1) Enter an integer (with some junk like units):  123 kg
2) Enter an integer (and some junk afterwards):  45 stones 5 pound
 quit
3) Enter the third integer:  238

First: 123, Second: 45, Third: 238
```

The code now works (with the need for entering "quit" at the second prompt), but I'm wondering whether there is a safer or better method for clearing out the scanner, so I can get it ready for reading the next input. Hopefully with the out endless loop fix. The output is as expected.

Comment: I don't understand what is your desired behaviour, what is your workaround, or why you would look for `"quit"` before continuing to the third prompt.

Comment: @200_success, I was thinking that I could do  `while (scanner.hasNext()) {scanner.next(); }` to flush the input buffer, but that turned in to  an endless loop, so to give myself a way out I added the lines with `// Fix ...`.   It was meant as alternative to just using a single `scanner.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the junk after the integer, you can make use of Scanner.skip(Pattern pattern). It allows you to skip over any set of characters that match a pattern:

scanner.skip(".*");

This method call will cause the Scanner to skip over any characters that match the pattern ".*"  .  The period character in a regular expression matches any single character.  The repetition character * causes matching zero or more of the previous character.  So the pattern .* will match zero or more of any characters.  Thus, it will skip over any characters currently on the stream. So now our code will look like:

```
    int myFirstInt = scanner.nextInt();
    // Ignore rest of line
    scanner.skip(".*");

    System.out.print("2) Enter an integer (and some junk afterwards): ");
    int mySecondInt = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip(".*");
    System.out.print("3) Enter the third integer: ");
    int myThirdInt = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("\nFirst: %d, Second: %d, Third: %d\n",
                      myFirstInt, mySecondInt, myThirdInt);
```

It is a simple way to flush the stream so that it is clear of bad characters, and ready to be reused!